# how read list inside list on dart(FLUTTER)

Tags: list, flutter, dart

```dart
final List _icons = [
    [
      'IDENTITY',
      FontAwesomeIcons.camera,
    ],
    [
      'SPECIES',
      FontAwesomeIcons.tree,
    ],
    [
      'ARTICLES',
      FontAwesomeIcons.bookOpen,
    ],
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
_icons[0][1] //FontAwesomeIcons.camera
```

but it seems like you can use a `map` instead of a `list`

```
final map _icons = { 'IDENTITY' : FontAwesomeIcons.camera, 'SPECIES': FontAwesomeIcons.tree, 'ARTICLES' : FontAwesomeIcons.bookOpen};
_icons['IDENTITY']; //FontAwesomeIcons.camera
```